# React Native - Text Input's Bottom Border

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

i'm trying to create a text input without border. i gave still and properties then this happened.

[text input img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm4Su.png)

There is a bottom border line with black color. how can i remove this border?

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper'
```

those are style codes

```
width: width * 0.6,
height: height * 0.075,
paddingLeft: 15,
fontSize: 12,
borderRadius: 25,
```

and text input

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.emptyPostPageTitleInput}
    placeholder="title"
    placeholderTextColor="grey"
    maxLength={17}/>
```

Comment: add borderWidth: 0 to your style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.62/textinput) states "TextInput has by default a border at the bottom of its view. This border has its padding set by the background image provided by the system, and it cannot be changed."

Still, if you add `borderBottomWidth: 0` to your styles, that should "remove" it.

For `react-native-paper`, the solution would be adding the following inside your component:

```
underlineColor="transparent"
```

Should look like this:

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.emptyPostPageTitleInput}
    placeholder="title"
    placeholderTextColor="grey"
    maxLength={17}
    underlineColor="transparent"/>
```

Comment: nothing has changed

Comment: by the way text input from react-native-paper for using left and right icons `import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper'
`

Comment: @ba_rt please make sure to point that out in the future. Making use of libraries does change the way stuff like this has to be handled.

Comment: i'm sorry. you right

Comment: @ba_rt edited my answer with the solution. Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

You can make your *borders invisible* by adding **simple styles** and don't need to install third party libraries like **(react-native-paper)**.

```js
import {TextInput} from "react-native";



<TextInput
          style={styles.dummy}
          placeholder="Email Address or UserName" />
```

And the styles are

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    dummy: {
    marginTop: 30,
    padding: 13,
    alignContent: "center",
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth:0,
    (// width: '85%',
    // height: 50,
    // borderColor: "#808080",
    // borderRadius: 10,
    // marginHorizontal: 22,
    // borderBottomWidth:0,
    // ) }        //You can use if you wanted. Not necessary.
```

And the output will look like the below image,[image]

Answer (score 0):

"In React Native Paper's TextInput, you can use the theme prop to customize the input style. For example, to remove the blue underline that appears when the input is active, you can set colors.underlineColor to transparent in the theme prop. Additionally, you can set underlineColor to transparent to remove the border bottom width. Here's an example code snippet:

```
  theme={{
          colors: {
          primary: 'transparent',
          underlineColor: 'transparent',
             },
          }}
    underlineColor="transparent"
```